# Trying to declare static member function - "is not a member of Class" error

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my code:

```
//portmanager.cpp
#include "portmanager.h"

void PortManager::setupQuestions() {
    QMap<QString, QVector<quint8>> commandMap;
    QVector<quint8> v;
    v = {0xF0, 0xC0, 0x4F}; commandMap.insert("check digit", v);
    //some code
    QVector<Question*> *questions = this->questions;
    for (QString commandKey : commandMap.keys()) {
        Question *question = new Question;
        question->name = commandKey;
        question->data = &commandMap[commandKey];
        question->byteData = Engine::dataToByteBata(question->data);
        questions->push_back(question);
    }
}

PortManager::PortManager(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    this->engine = (Engine*) parent;
    this->setupQuestions();
}
```

It gives me error like this:

> portmanager.cpp:19: error: 'dataToByteBata' is not a member of 'Engine'
>
> question->byteData = Engine::dataToByteBata(question->data);

but I'm pretty sure it is a member:

```
//engine.h
#include "mainwindow.h"

class DatabaseManager;
class PortManager;

class Engine : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    static QByteArray dataToByteData(QVector<quint8> const& data) {
        QByteArray* byteData = new QByteArray;
        for (quint8 h : data) {
            byteData->append(h);
        }
        return *byteData;
    }

    explicit Engine(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

private:
    MainWindow *mainWindow;
    DatabaseManager *databaseManager;
    PortManager *portManager;
    QTimer *timer;
};
```

In the moment the function is called, Engine is not yet fully constructed but already fully declared:

```
//engine.cpp
#include "engine.h"
#include "databasemanager.h"
#include "portmanager.h"

Engine::Engine(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    this->mainWindow = (MainWindow*) parent;
    this->databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(this);
    this->portManager = new PortManager(this);
}
```

but it's static function so it should be there just like I would use namespace rather than class, right? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you include `engine.h` in `portmanager.cpp`?

Comment: have you included engine.h? Can't see it!

Comment: Unrelated: in `dataToByteData` you are leaking memory. Do not use `new` to create `QByteArray`, just create it so: `QByteArray byteData;` and then use `byteData.append(h)`.

Comment: Simple typo, unlikely to help anyone else in the future.

Comment: sorry, guys... :P flagged for deletion, I was looking at it for an hour... need a break, I guess...

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't really understand the idea of leaking memory yet, will look into that.

Comment: Man please try to post errors you actually see. What's that? Check your importations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dataToByteBata` is not the same as `dataToByteData`. /thread

Comment: `/career` more like ;p

Comment: sorry... -_-' I'll flag for deletion.

Comment: Be lenient please. It ain't easy learning a new language

Comment: @smsware: don't worry, there is a specific close reason for typographic errors; when you are engrossed into it your code, it's the kind of things your eyes gloss over...